# Retrieving an iterator for a HashMap throws a cast exception

Tags: java, iterator, hashmap

I have some relatively simple code I have made that is **supposed to retrieve an iterator to a HashMap & print out the key pair values**.

My problem is that when I go to retrieve the iterator I get this exception thrown.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap$Entry cannot be cast to java.lang.String
>        at Delete.main(Delete.java:25)

Here is my code & I point out where line 25 is:

```
    Map <String, UpdatablePage> contentMap = new HashMap <String, UpdatablePage>();
    contentMap.put( "test", new UpdatablePage() );

    for ( Iterator it = (Iterator) contentMap.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext(); )
    {
        String key = (String) it.next();  // LINE 25
        UpdatablePage value = contentMap.get(key);
        System.out.print( "Key=" + key + ", Value=" + value.toString() );
    }
```

PS, I have tried to iterate over a map using the Map.Entry but when I go to cast the value returned by the iterator to a Map.Entry I get another casting exception, why?

```
// Error occurs when I do the following
Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this line:
for ( Iterator it = (Iterator) contentMap.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext(); )

entrySet() should be keySet() - your iterator returns each entry but as you're casting them to String, I presume it's the keys you want.

Answer (score 2):

When iterating the entry set you get back `Map.Entry` objects, on which you can then use `getKey()` and `getValue()` to extract the key and value.  No need to iterate the keys and separately extract the value (which is much less efficient).

By the way, you would not cast the *iterator* to Map.Entry, but the object which the iterator returns on each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Use keySet() and a generic iterator for best results:

```
  Map<String, UpdatablePage> contentMap = new HashMap<String, UpdatablePage>();
  contentMap.put("test", new UpdatablePage());

  for (Iterator<String> it = contentMap.keySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
     String key = it.next();
     UpdatablePage value = contentMap.get(key);
     System.out.print("Key=" + key + ", Value=" + value.toString());
  }
```

With the generic iterator, there's no need for any casts at all, and you get the benefit of compile-time type checking rather than runtime exception as you're seeing.

Comment: Better yet, use the enhanced for.